# creating git repo and following instructions exactly giving me errors

Tags: git, github

the usual way that I create my git repos, is on the website, and then clone them.
I wanted to try the other way around, calling git init in my command line.

So I create a repo with nothing in it, and get these steps shown to me:

```
echo "# malware" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin git@github.com:S3j5b0/malware.git
git push -u origin main
```

Great, I follow these instructions exactly in my command line, and in the last line, I get:

```
ask@garser:~/Git/malwa$ git push -u origin main
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What is happening?

Comment: Have you uploaded a public key to GitHub? Do you have an SSH Agent running?

Comment: no, no keys added

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Permission+denied+publickey

Answer (score -1):

Did you setup your git user name and email? Try with

```
git config --global user.name "Mona Lisa"
git config --global user.email "monalisa@gmail.com"
```

Please make sure that your username has access to the project repo!

If this didn't work then edit your remote `origin` with the HTTPS Url using

`git remote set-url origin YOUR_HTTPS_URL`

You can find the URL in your repo as below.

[image]

Comment: setting email and user does not work, and using https doesnt either